# SQL server, Find all columns that are contained in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table:

```
Id int, 
Name varchar(10)
```

with values:

```
(1, Nick), (2, Mike), (3, Eric)
```

I want to return all the names that are contained in a string. For example "Nick, Mick" would return Nick and Mike.

I've tried with `LIKE` but it works the other way around returning the values that contain a string.

I was hoping for somthing like this, but that it actually works.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Name.isContained("Nick, Mike");
```

Result:

```
1, Nick and 2, Mike
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? in your example "...,Mick" would return ...,Mike ?

Comment: you need a string in one row only?

Comment: Yes. Basicaly whatever substring that is contained in the search string is a valid match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select name from tbl_sound where  SOUNDEX(`name`) like '%00%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM mytable
WHERE PATINDEX('%'+Name+'%', 'Nick, Mike') > 0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41384/2)

Comment: Just trim any trailing spaces other wise it wont find the matches

Answer (score 0):

Demo. Finds exact names match

```
create table demo (
    Id int, 
Name varchar(10));

insert demo
values
(1, 'Nick'), (2, 'Mike'), (3, 'Eric');

declare @prm varchar(200) = 'Nick,Mike,Ann';
select *  
from demo
where ','+ @prm +',' like '%,'+Name+',%'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
        declare @tmp nvarchar(250)
        SET @tmp = ''
        select  @tmp = @tmp + concat(ID,' , ',name,' and ') 
        from table
        where Name in ('Nick','Mike')

        select SUBSTRING(@tmp, -2, LEN(@tmp))
```

> OutPut :

[image]